# How to store multiple input in array?

Tags: javascript, php

Here is javascript code to add input field in on click but while storing only one row is stored . How to store all the row?

```
<div class = "row" id="dynamic_field">
    <div class = "input-field col s12">
      <input id = "list-title" name = "post[title]" type = "text" class = "validate" required value = "<">
      <label for = "list-title ">Title</label>
    </div>
</div>


 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#added').click(function () {
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<div class="row">' +
              '<div class = "input-field col s12" >\n' +
              ' \n' +
                '<input id = "list-title " name = "post[title]" type = "text" class = "validate" required value = "">\n' +
                '<label for = "list-title ">Title</label>\n' +
              '</div>'+
              '</div>'
        );
       });
  });
```

Here is my php code in store controller.

```
public function UpdateController() {
    if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
        $data = $_POST['post']
        $model->title = $data['title'];
    }
    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: try with "post[][title]" (if you want an array of titles)

Comment: Well first of all you are not looping over the array being sent, assuming it is being sent

Comment: `name = "post[title][]"` because `name = "post[title]"` whil eit is an array is one occurance with a key of `title`

Comment: Cant be sure, cant see the rest of the code, but it may be simpler to call it `name = "title[]"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you it worked